# track down file handle

Tags: java, logging, file, jakarta-ee, websphere

I have a huge ear that uses log4j and there is a single config file that is used to set it up. In this config file there is no mention of certain log files but, additional files apart from those specified in the config file get generated in the logs folder. I've searched for other combinations of (logger|log4j|log).(properties|xml) and haven't found anything promising in all of the jar files included in the ear. How do I track down which is the offending thread/class that is creating these extra files?

Comment: What app server are you running? And what files are being created?

Comment: WAS 6.1 and apart from appName-(error|info|debug).log there are error.log and debug.log

Comment: Hmm, you might want to tag your post with `websphere` & `was`. See if any experts in those have any suggestions.

Comment: thx. good idea :) will do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try placing a breakpoint in the File class' constructors and the mkdir and createNewFile methods.  Generally, code will use the File class to create its files or directories.  You should have the Java source code for these classes included with your JVM.

Comment: It took a lot of time hitting F8 but I tracked it down :) thx

Comment: shyam, you can use conditional breakpoint as well. A condition looks like this for example: this.path.endsWith("bla")

Answer (score 3):

Add `-Dlog4j.debug` to the command line and there will be extra info in standard output about how it is configured.

Answer (score 0):

Formally SysInternal's, now Microsoft's Process Explorer
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

"Find" menu item -> "Find Handle or DLL..."

Comment: Already tried that :( But, when I search from the appserver's java process all files and directories I see are of those of the appserver itself my log directory doesn't figure in those. btw i'm using WAS 6.1. But, I plan to take a deeper look into procexp

Answer (score 0):

SysInternals may not help with Java class IO.  Try getting a thread dump of the JVM (e.g., kill -3) while these logs are being written to.  You should be able to catch a thread red handed with java.io packages near the top of the stack trace.